# Finding maximum value

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, inequality, systems-of-equations, maxima-minima

The question is :

> Let $a,$$b,$$c$ be positive real numbers such that 
>   $ \frac{a}{1+b} + \frac{b}{1+c} + \frac{c}{1+a} =1$
>   Then find the maximum value of $abc$.

I just blindly simplified the equation and  wrote $abc$ on LHS and other terms on RHS so I concluded if I could find the maximum value of RHS that would help but i am unable to do that also .please tell what would be the correct approach and method for the question .This question requires a subjective approach (not trial and error).

Comment: I see. I'll delete my comment, thank you for clarifying.

Comment: @AkshajBansal reread my comment. I don't understand the question

Comment: @AkshajBansal also, doesn't $a=b=c=1/2$ make each fractional term on the LHS equal to $\frac{1}{3}$?

Comment: Ok thanks i edited the question

Comment: @AkshajBansal No, i am still confused by the question. You start the question by fixing $a,b$, and $c$. Then you ask for the maximum of $abc$. Asking for the maximum confuses me, since you already fixed $a,b$, and $c$. What are you taking the maximum over?

Comment: @mathworker21 We need to find a maximal value of $abc$ under the condition.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg but aren't $a,b$, and $c$ fixed???? What condition is there? Akshaj is describing properties of $a,b$, and $c$

Comment: @mathworker21 The condition is $\frac{a}{1+b} + \frac{b}{1+c} + \frac{c}{1+a} =1$. Also, $a$, $b$ and $c$ are changed under this condition and $abc$ is changed. We need to find a maximal value of $abc$ under this condition.

Comment: @mathworker21 See please better my previous post. Take for example the following simpler statement. Let $a$ and $b$ be positive numbers such that $a+b=2$. It says that I can take $a=\frac{1}{2}$, $b=\frac{3}{2}$ or I can take $a=b=1$ or more infinitely many possibilities. I did not like your last words. Stop it please.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg I really didn't mean to be rude; I just wanted to express my thoughts objectively. In my mind, when you say "let $a$ and $b$ be ...", you are fixing $a$ and $b$. Of course they can be $\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{2}$ or $1,1$, but it does not make sense to say "what is the maximum of $ab$", since $ab$ is fixed. Actually, this is not just "in my mind". I think I am objectively correct.

Comment: @mathworker21 Now, for $a=\frac{1}{2}$ and $b=\frac{3}{2}$ we obtain $ab=\frac{3}{4}$, but if we change $a$ and $b$ such that $a+b=2$ so $ab$ can be changed. The maximal value of $ab$, which we can get by this way it's $1$ and occurs for $a=b=1$. I hope you understood it now.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg I was talking about the specific wording of the question, which you keep failing to address.

Comment: This really beyond my imaganation that with which part of question you are confused with.For more clarification as you are saying that $a,b,c$ are determined but its not true a,b,c may infinite many solution to the equation given so how are they fixed if there would have been three simultaneous equation in three variables $a,b,c$ then it must have definite values of $a,b,c$ which must satisfy the conditions.Over here sincle a,b,c may have many possible values you need to find those values of $a,b,c$ for which $abc$ is maximum that means u set those values of $a,b,c$ for which product is maximu

Comment: @AkshajBansal I have made myself perfectly clear, but you and michael are not understanding, for whatever reason. When you say "let $a,b,c$ be..." you *are fixing* them. This is not complicated. You either refuse to read my comments or are not capable of understanding. I am not being rude; this is the truth.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{a}{1+b}=\frac{\sum\limits_{cyc}a^2c+\sum\limits_{cyc}ac+\sum\limits_{cyc}a^2+\sum\limits_{cyc}a}{\sum\limits_{cyc}a+\sum\limits_{cyc}ac+1+abc}=1$

$\sum\limits_{cyc}a^2c+\sum\limits_{cyc}a^2=abc+1$

$1=\sum\limits_{cyc}a^2c+\sum\limits_{cyc}a^2-abc\geq 3abc+3\sqrt[3]{a^2b^2c^2}-abc\geq 2abc+3\sqrt[3]{a^2b^2c^2}=2t^3+3t^2$

Where $t=\sqrt[3]{abc}$. Can you finish from here?

Answer (score 4):

After full  expanding by AM-GM we obtain:
$$1+abc=\sum_{cyc}(a^2+a^2c)\geq3\left(\sqrt[3]{a^2b^2c^2}+abc\right).$$
The equality occurs for $a=b=c.$

Can you end it now?

I got $\frac{1}{8}$ as the answer.

Comment: Yes thanks i got that too

Comment: @Akshaj Bansal You are welcome!